# Search function through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter

I am very new in react and needed a search function which result should return match ‘in category’, ‘in subcategory’, ‘in product’, similar endpoint below.
My code below only return match when user input productname and null if search with categoryname or subcategoryname

My Code

```
const SearchSection = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const theme = useTheme();

  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState("")

  const handleFilter = e =>{
     const searchWord = e.target.value
     setInputData(searchWord)
     const newFilter = categories.filter((product ) => {
           return product.productname.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase())
     })

     if(searchWord === "") {
           setFilteredData([])
     }else {
           setFilteredData(newFilter ) 
     }
  }

  console.log(filteredData)
 return (
  <>
     <Navbar />
     <div className={classes.hero}>

        <div className={classes.overlay}></div>

        <div className={classes.heroContentContainer}>

           <div className={classes.heroSection}>
                 <div className={classes.SearchBar} >
                    <SearchField value={inputData} onChange={handleFilter} name="search" />
                 </div>
           </div>

        </div>
        
     </div>

     <Container>
             {filteredData.map(productName =>{
                return(
                   <SearchCard productName={productName}  />
                )
            })} 
     </Container>

  </>);};
```

endpoints data structures

```
[
{
    "_id": "61afe234d43c9ad47188bff3",
    "categoryname": "Restaurant",
    "subcategory": [
        {
            "_id": "61b3823901e636b6782375ef",
            "subcategoryname": "Grilled Food",
            "subcategoryimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg",
            "product": [
                {
                    "_id": "61daec0b29f2c8c9337fa593",
                    "productname": "Poultry",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "61daec1729f2c8c9337fa59c",
                    "productname": "Fish",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/ajeo/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "61daec2529f2c8c9337fa5a2",
                    "productname": "Vegetarian",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "_id": "61b3824501e636b6782375f3",
            "subcategoryname": "Traditional delicacies",
            "subcategoryimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg",
            "product": [
                {
                    "_id": "61daee16d94f72b6d15396a8",
                    "productname": "Peppered meat",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "_id": "61b3824e01e636b6782375f7",
            "subcategoryname": "Crustacean",
            "subcategoryimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg",
            "product": [
                {
                    "_id": "61daee55d94f72b6d15396f8",
                    "productname": "Seafood",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "_id": "61b3825601e636b6782375fb",
            "subcategoryname": "Sandwiches",
            "subcategoryimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/ajeo/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg",
            "product": [
                {
                    "_id": "61b3839d01e636b678237638",
                    "productname": "Pizza",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg",
                    "imageurl": "uploads/placeholder-1639154589069-957455144.jpeg",
                    "productdescription": "undefined"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "61daeee9d94f72b6d1539784",
                    "productname": "Shawarma",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "61daef43d94f72b6d15397c9",
                    "productname": "Burger",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "_id": "61daeae829f2c8c9337fa4f0",
            "subcategoryname": "Drinks",
            "imageurl": "",
            "product": [
                {
                    "_id": "61daef69d94f72b6d15397fa",
                    "productname": "Cocktail",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "61daef72d94f72b6d1539800",
                    "productname": "Alcoholic drinks",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "61daef79d94f72b6d1539806",
                    "productname": "Juice",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                },
            ],
            "subcategoryimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/ajeo/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg",
    ],
},
 {
    "_id": "61afe234d43c9ad47188bf",
    "categoryname": "Dining",
    "subcategory": [
        {
            "_id": "61b3823901e636b6782375ef",
            "subcategoryname": "Shawama",
            "subcategoryimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg",
            "product": [
                {
                    "_id": "61daec0b29f2c8c9337fa593",
                    "productname": "Bird",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "61daec1729f2c8c9337fa59c",
                    "productname": "Cat",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/ajeo/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "61daec2529f2c8c9337fa5a2",
                    "productname": "Vegans",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "_id": "61b3824501e636b6782375f3",
            "subcategoryname": "Delicacies",
            "subcategoryimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg",
            "product": [
                {
                    "_id": "61daee16d94f72b6d15396a8",
                    "productname": "Meat",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "_id": "61b3824e01e636b6782375f7",
            "subcategoryname": "Crust",
            "subcategoryimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg",
            "product": [
                {
                    "_id": "61daee55d94f72b6d15396f8",
                    "productname": "food",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "_id": "61b3825601e636b6782375fb",
            "subcategoryname": "Sand",
            "subcategoryimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/ajeo/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg",
            "product": [
                {
                    "_id": "61b3839d01e636b678237638",
                    "productname": "Pizza",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg",
                    "imageurl": "uploads/placeholder-1639154589069-957455144.jpeg",
                    "productdescription": "undefined"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "61daef43d94f72b6d15397c9",
                    "productname": "Burger",
                    "productdescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ",
                    "productimage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1642037819/uploads/placeholder_kmytyw.jpg"
                }
            ],
        },
    ],
},]
```

Answer (score 0):

For client side search it might be easier to use an existing library, for example [Fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/) rather than implementing a search yourself. It's quite easy to implement and works pretty well.

They have a [live demo](https://fusejs.io/demo.html) on their website, you can see if it's something that would fit your requirements.

Comment: I will check and revert